# How to call an object inside a function?

Tags: lua

How to call an object inside a function? Example: The `pencil` object is inside a function, and after closing it, I have to use

```
pencil:removeEventListener ("touch", moveLapis)
```

How do I do that?

For when I call it normally, an error saying that the pencil is `nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Objects inside functions can only be called inside that scope, to be able to call it from outside, you would have to move your `pencil` object to outside the function, or add a reference outside the function to it.

For example:

```
local pencil
local function myFunction()
   pencil = newPencil()
end

if pencil then
    pencil:removeEventListener ("touch", moveLapis)
end
```

Of course, you would have to check if pencil has a value or some kind of verification before calling the function, to avoid an error.

Comment: This, or if you can only get the `pencil` object in the function and really need to remove the event listener after the function call, you could return it from the function.

Comment: Well, this certainly does not solve my case, since all code is inside a function, if I put a "if" will give me many problems ... But thanks for trying to help {: